# Javascript - Comparing two arrays then pushing to new array on condition met

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Is there any way to compare two arrays and push to an empty array if the condition is met?

Say I have an array of objects. I need to loop through the array of objects, get a ID; then compare that ID to a different array. Then if they match push a value in that array to an empty array?

Array 1:

```
[{
    "addon_service": {
        "id": "f6f28cb5-78ad-4ec7-896d-16462b8202fd",
        "name": "papertrail"          
    },
    "app": {
        "id": "199a1f26-b8e2-43f6-9bab-6e7a6c685ec2",
        "name": "mdda-mobiledocdelivery-stg"
    }
}]
```

Array 2

```
[{
    "app": {
        "id": "199a1f26-b8e2-43f6-9bab-6e7a6c685ec2"
    },
    "stage": "staging",
}]
```

I need to match Array 1 app.ID to Array 2 app.id. If they match check what stage the app is in (staging, development or production). Then push Array 1 addon_service.name to either a staging develpment or 
production array depending on what stage the application is in. I'm thinking its simple just cant get my head around it.

I think this is a poorly worded question.

Comment: and how should look the resulting *empty array* ?

Comment: Take a look at Array.prototype.filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for lookup and for the stage and use an object for collecting the matches.

```js
var array1 = [{ "addon_service": { "id": "f6f28cb5-78ad-4ec7-896d-16462b8202fd", "name": "papertrail" }, "app": { "id": "199a1f26-b8e2-43f6-9bab-6e7a6c685ec2", "name": "mdda-mobiledocdelivery-stg" } }],
    array2 = [{ "app": { "id": "199a1f26-b8e2-43f6-9bab-6e7a6c685ec2" }, "stage": "staging", }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = {};

array2.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.app.id] = a.stage;
});

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    if (hash[a.app.id]) {
        result[hash[a.app.id]] = result[hash[a.app.id]] || [];
        result[hash[a.app.id]].push(a.addon_service.name);
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it.

```
$.each(app1, function(key, value){
  $.each(app2, function(k, v){
    if(value.app.id == v.app.id){// find apps with the same `id`
      if(v[v.stage]){// check if the `stage` array already exists.
        v[v.stage].push(value.addon_service)
      }else{
         v[v.stage] = [value.addon_service];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Where `app1` is the first array in your question and `app2` the second one.